# dragular.js: Nested Elements and Adding New Elements

Tags: dragula

Does anybody know how nested elements and add new elements in dragula.js work together?

I've come this far: nested elements works, adding elemnts works, too, but I can't move a nested element into an new element:

```
https://codepen.io/BerndBammer/pen/NLMKpN
```

How can I destroy dragula and refresh it?

thx & best regards,

Bernd

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I updated the CodePen, works now fine